# CAP_V4L is not a member of cv in cap_.open

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, ros, catkin

I'm trying launch cv_camera with ros but I couldn't compile this package in ros, I launched this command:

```
catkin_make --only-pkg-with-deps rossumo cv_camera -DARDRONESDK3_PATH=~/out/arsdk-native/staging/usr
...
/home/docker/catkin_ws/src/cv_camera/src/capture.cpp: In member function ‘void cv_camera::Capture::open(const string&)’:
/home/docker/catkin_ws/src/cv_camera/src/capture.cpp:95:26: error: ‘CAP_V4L’ is not a member of ‘cv’
   cap_.open(device_path, cv::CAP_V4L);
                          ^
make[2]: *** [cv_camera/CMakeFiles/cv_camera.dir/src/capture.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [cv_camera/CMakeFiles/cv_camera.dir/all] Error 2
```

What do you think I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Call function `cv::getBuildInformation()`. In the output text find the string `V4L/V4L2` and check it's value. If it's No/No then your opencv was not built with V4L support.

Comment: thanks! I builded with 4vl support